# incorprating css and html elements into php

Tags: php, html, css

I have a bunch of php files that I want to incorporate html (divs) and css (external stylesheets) elements into.

If any one has any tips / ideas on how to go about doing this I'd love to hear them :)

Comment: define your understanding of the word "incorporate"

Answer (score 5):

You could either :

- Integrate HTML code in your PHP file,
- Or have your PHP script echo the HTML content.

With the first solution, your PHP file could look like this :

```
<?php 
    $var = 10;
    // some PHP code
?>
<div>
    this is some HTML
</div>
<?php
    // and some PHP code again
?>
```

For more informations about this, see the following section of the manual : [**Escaping from HTML**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php).

While, with the second solution, your PHP file could look like this :

```
<?php
    $var = 10;
    // some PHP code

    echo '<div>this is some HTML</div>';

    // and some PHP code again

?>
```

Basically, you are free to mix HTML and PHP code in the same PHP script : outside of `<?php ... ?>` tags, things will not get interpreted as PHP code.

Comment: Additionally, chunks of static HTML, or whole pages, can be included with the [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) statement. CSS and Javascript could also be incorporated in this way, but as HTML already defines methods for including these assets cacheably, it is not recommended. Finally, a useful syntactic alternative to the second method Pascal mentioned is the [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) string delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is exit php and write html as normal:

```
<?php
// php code
?>

<div>
  <p>Some html</p>
</div>

<?php
// more php code
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the PHP alternative syntax for control structures. It is often times more comprehensive when you start mixing with plain HTML:

```
<?php if(...): ?>

<p>paragraph</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Instead of:

```
<?php if(...) { ?>

<p>paragraph</p>

<?php } ?>
```